# Sticking GP Strokes to Mesh Surface with Bendy Bones

Tags: armature, grease-pencil

I have a mesh parented to bendy bones. I have created some grease pencil strokes on the surface of the mesh. The problem is, when the mesh is deformed by bbones, the GP strokes get detached from the surface. I tried parenting the GP object to the same armature but that doesn't work.
How can I make the GP strokes stick to the surface even after the deformation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 methods I can think of for good results:

One is to turn the GP object into a texture and apply it to the mesh material.

Two is to turno the GP object into a mesh and parent it to the rig.

Three is to add a lattice modifier and set the rig to deform the lattice and the lattice to deform the GP object (needs careful weight painting).

An image of the project could help to choose the best approach.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me how to turn GP strokes into texture? I did not find the option anywhere.

Comment: You have to set a camera, create a render, save it as image and use the image as texture of the surface of the mesh.